# My JTAG connection with Cyclone IV is not working

Tags: fpga, jtag, cyclone

My FPGA board is not programming. I think I have followed all the guide lines for JTAG connection. Can you see any problems with this connection?[image: Cyclone IV Board]

Comment: Are there any errors thrown by the software you're using to program it?

Comment: Looks good to me. Any reason the pull-down for TCK is 1k, not 10k like the others? Check the clock waveform, after that it's logic analyzer time.

Comment: @SimonRichter The guidelines specifies a 1k resistor for TCK and a 10k resistor for the others. Do you know what this port 1 of the xtal means? The datasheet only have the E/D label in this pin. I'm thinking this is Enable/Disable and so I must connect it to VCC.

Comment: Crystal datasheet.
https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/Yangxing-Tech-50MHz-25PPM_C112970.pdf

Comment: The JTAG port does not need the rest of the FPGA to be clocked (because config load includes the clock routing), so that should not have any influence on being able to use JTAG.